# Can't connect SSH from VM to other computer

Tags: centos, ssh, virtualbox, timeout

I connected on my network, two computers, one is hosting a virtual machine(CentOS) connected as Bridge, the other is a Debian.

Host (Windows 10 - 10.10.10.2) - Vm (10.10.10.3) - Debian(10.10.10.4)

I can connect on SSH from Host to Debian, there is no problem. But, i need to connect on SSH from Vm to Debian and when i tried, i've got a "connection timed out", i can ping my Debian from my Vm.

Host --> Debian SSH OK
Vm --> Debian SSH NOK
Vm --> Debian PING OK

What's the problem ?
Thx.

Comment: What OS is running on the host? Please [edit] your question to add more information, don't use comments for this. You could use Wireshark to check if the SSH packets reach your Debian system and if it sends response packets.

Comment: Windows as Host. can't intstall anything on the debian.

Comment: What error message do you get on the SSH client side?

Comment: I just got the message "Connection timed out"

Comment: @Y.op **Please [edit] your question to add information instead of answering in comments.** Which Windows version? Check the Windows firewall settings. Do you have sufficient rules to accept the traffic to/from the VM? If you can't install anything on the Debian system, try the same with a different system where you can install software. Or ask the responsible person for help.